# Declaring function with the same name but different arguments in a derived contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, inheritance

What happens if one declares a function with the same name as a function in a base contract, but with different arguments in a derived contract?

How does it behave with different combinations of presence/absence of `virtual` modifier?

What's in different version of Solidity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the solidity compiler they are completely different functions.

At runtime functions are identified by their 4 bytes selector. The function selector is calculated from the function name and the parameter types ([Function Selector](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/abi-spec.html#function-selector)). If the function name remains the same but the parameters change it is very likely the selector will be different.

The virtual modifier indicates which functions can be overridden. It doesn't change the function selector.

The algorithm uses to calculate a selector is part of the ABI and doesn't depend on the solidity version used. It is possible it change in the future but that option seems unlikely.